# How to call native functions from a VM?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

*By native I mean written in C++ or C*

I'm making a programming language based off Java, in that it has a VM and a language to bytecode compiler.

Implementing the language's features, such as `for` loops, variables, arithmetic and so on, isn't a problem for me; however, executing native functions like Java can is.

I need the native functions in order to make it possible for programs written in my language to create windows, interface with hardware and the OS, and do just about anything that isn't simple mathematics.

I've heard about the [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface#How_the_JNI_works), and it definitely seems like something I'd want, however, I am not sure how to implement something like that.

As my VM is implemented in C++, I know that I could have it `#include` hpp files of my native functions at compile-time, and then it could dynamically load `dll`'s or `so`'s, however, this doesn't really seem like a good solution because you'd have to recompile the VM every time you'd want it to be able to execute another native function.

The problem comes down to this: how can a C++ program (the VM), dynamically (at runtime, as instructed by bytecode, to be more precise) load libraries with C++ functions, and then execute those functions without them being predeclared in some header file?

Comment: Will you please provide some code sample what you want ?

Comment: On Windows you use LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress().  Linux has equivalent functions with different names.  These do not help you know number the number and types of the arguments and return value.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani Sure, as soon as I get home in a few hours.

Comment: @brianbeuning - I do know the return type and the types of the arguments actually, as that function is created in my language which has equivalents of C/C++ types. Is it possible to declare a function at run-time or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/).  It provides methods to call any function given a function address and a calling signature.

How you figure out what that signature should be depends on your context.  You can infer a wide range of calls based on argument types.  [JNA](http://github.com/twall/jna) infers native call signatures from explicit Java interfaces, method declarations, or dynamic call arguments.

Going beyond simple function invocations to handle constructors, memory management, and object method dispatching is more complex, but is still based the same basic principles.

Comment: This definitely seems like something I need. However, I am not exactly sure as to how am I supposed to get a pointer to a function in some dynamically loaded shared object (`dlopen()`). I know the name, the number of arguments, the types of the arguments and the return type of the function itself, because that is described in my language, but I'm not sure how to get the pointer to the native function. If I know that the native function will be called `X`, can I get a pointer to it?

Comment: `dlsym()` looks up a symbol given the name.  Usually exported symbols are either functions you can call or addresses of global variables for data access.

Comment: Now that I've got `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`, where's the actual need for LibFFI?

Comment: Said the FedEx guy, "I've got a name and an address, what else could I need?".  If your language already knows how to put arguments on the stack and/or in registers in preparation for a function call, then you *don't* need libffi.  But since you say your language is based on Java/bytecode and not C/C++ and you suggest the need to do things dynamically, I'm guessing it doesn't.

Comment: Well, *my* language is based off Java, but the VM is implemented in C++. If `dlsym()` gets me a pointer to a function I'd like to execute, the C++ compiler should be able to handle that, right? Or, is it the case that the compiler can't handle it, because it doesn't know anything about the specific function being executed at compile-time? I hoped that something like this could actually be fixed by my VM knowing which types of arguments are needed by the function.

Comment: You can certainly make your VM do the work (push arg1, push arg2, extract/return result), but it'll essentially need to perform the work that libffi does in ensuring that the different arguments are placed on the stack properly, and then that the return value is read back properly.

Answer (score 0):

One topic I have not seen discussed is how to pass arguments from your new language VM function calls to the C++ stack, and how to pass the return value from the C++ function back into your VM.

Lets say you want to make the pow(3) function available in your new language.
As a reminder, the pow() signature is

```
double pow ( double base, double power )
```

The simplest way is something like this

```
void
language::pow( VM * pVM )
{
    double arg2 = pVM->PopDouble();
    double arg1 = pVM->PopDouble();
    double result = pow( arg1, arg2 );
    pVM->PushDouble( result );
}
```

But that does not sound like what you are after. Incorporating dlopen() & dlsym() gets your something like

```
void
language::pow( VM * pVM )
{
    double arg2 = pVM->PopDouble();
    double arg1 = pVM->PopDouble();
    void *handle = dlopen("libm", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) { /*...return; ...*/ }
    typedef double (* pfPow ) ( double, double );
    pfPow pPow = (pfPow) dlsym(handle, "pow");
    if (!pPow) { /*...return; ...*/ }
    double result = (* pPow )( arg1, arg2 );
    pVM->PushDouble( result );
}
```

But that is even worse. You still need a stub function per C++ function you want your language to be able to access.

It sounds like you want your language to have something like

```
double result = eval_double( "libm", "pow", arg1, arg2 );
```

I do not know how to implement that in C++. Varags supports fetching C++ arguments of any type. But there is no API for pushing C++ arguments of arbitrary type.